# Joint Distribution Formulation of a Spatial X, Spatial Y, and Spatial Error Model

Tags: covariance, covariance-matrix, spatial, generalized-least-squares, distance-covariance

Introductory Problem:

I have $n$ points in 3-D space, where I know their X and Y coordinates (not Z), and therefore the distances between points in those 2 dimensions. Each of the three dimensions has a variable evolving in that dimension so that the further apart the points, the more they have evolved, and the less they are related to each other.  I know the covariance between $x_{i}$ and $x_{j}$ is $(1-d_{xij})\sigma_{x}^2$ where $d_{xij}$ is the distance between $x_{i}$ and $x_{j}$ and $\sigma_{x}^2$ is the variance of $X$.  All the same logic applies for the $Y$ variable as well.  Thus if point $i$ and point $j$ are in the same location, their distance is zero, and their covariance is $\sigma^2$.  If they are one unit away, their covariance is $0$, and the points will never be farther away from each other than one unit.

Now, I need to infer $\sigma_{z}^2$, and $d_{zij}$ for all $z_{i}$, $z_{j}$ subject to $y_{i}=\beta_{0}+\beta_{1}x_{i}+z_{i} (Eqn. 1)$.

Actual Problem:

Perhaps fGLS would work for the above problem, but it doesn't work for my real problem where the distances of none of the points is "known."  What I actually know is that the points exist in just one dimension, and I do know their distances, but focusing on $X$, for example, the actual variance-covariance relationship describing the relationship between $x_{i}$ and $x_{j}$ is not the matrix $\sigma_{x}^{2}D_{(1-d)}$, of closeness, but actually a linear combination of this and white noise, so $cov(x_{i}.x_{j})$ is the $i$th, $j$th entry of matrix resulting from this sum:
$$
(\lambda_{x})\sigma_{x}^{2}D_{(1-d)}+(1-\lambda_{x})\sigma_{x}^{2}\mathbb{I}_n,
$$
where $\mathbb{I}_n$ is the Identity matrix.

The $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ points all have this spatial structure with the same closeness and identity matrices but different values of $\lambda$, where generally $\lambda_{x}\neq\lambda_{y}\neq\lambda_{z}$.

My best idea so far is to make a variance-covariance matrix of size (3$n$ x 3$n$) where for example, the entry at the $n$+$i$th row and 2$n$+$j$th column gives the covariance of $y_{i}$ and $z_{j}$, create a formula for each entry, and then fit the parameter values by maximum likelihood (assuming the variance-covariance matrix describes a multivariate normal of 3$n$ dimensions).  But I'm not really confident about which formulas properly describe the relationships true to the original relationship specified above in Eqn. 1.

I need help with the formulas for $cov(x_{i},y_{j})$, $cov(x_{i},z_{j})$, and $cov(y_{i},z_{j})$.  Because $Z$ is my error, it is supposed to be independent of $X$ and $Y$.  So maybe $cov(x_{i},z_{j})$=$cov(y_{i},z_{j})$=0?  If that's true, then I only need help with $cov(x_{i},y_{j})$.  But maybe even if we assume $Z$ is independent, because it's spatial structure is related to that of $X$ and $Y$ there will be some phantom correlation?

Thank you!